# maven profile can't get the site.url

Tags: java, maven, profile

working with java project with Maven and TestNG. Trying to put environment variables into maven profiles and call them on with mvn clean install -Pdevhost

The problen is that browser can't get a siteurl. Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null value in entry: url=null
```

Pom file profiles:

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <file>${project.basedir}/suites/smoke.xml</file>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <environment.properties>/environment.properties</environment.properties>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src\test\resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src\test\resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

</build>

    <!-- Profiles configuration -->
    <profiles>

        <!--Environments "mvn test -P dev3"-->

        <profile>
            <id>devhost</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <site.url>https://siteurl.com</site.url>
            </properties>
        </profile>
</profiles>
```

The file with properties called as "environment.properties" file and is located under src/test/resources:

```
site.url=${site.url}
```

Java class where driver gets the siteurl:

```
public void SetUp() {


    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
    ConfigFileReader.getDriverPath());

    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.get(System.getProperty("site.url"));

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: Are any other profiles active? `activeByDefault` doesn't mean "always active." It means "active if and only if no other profile is active." Though I would expect it to be okay with the profile specified on command line as you have it.

Comment: None but devhost profile is active or even exists.

Comment: If you look in `target/classes/environment.properties`, does `site.url` have the expected value? If yes, Maven is filtering properly. Just because a property exists in a properties file that's on the classpath doesn't mean it will end up as a System property.

Answer (score 0):

Added property loader into java class.

```
 PropertyLoader config = new PropertyLoader();
 baseUrl = config.getProperty("site.url");
 driver.get(baseUrl);
```